# Display Alphabetic Ordered List in Oracle Apex page

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 5 and wanted to display a beverage list in my page in alphabetic order like this (example).

a. Coffee
b. Tea
c. Juice

For this I have used PL/SQL block and used the code below (example) :

```
 BEGIN
    sys.htp.prn('<ol type = "a">');
      sys.htp.prn('<li>' || 'Coffee' || '</li>');
    sys.htp.prn('</ol>');
    END;
```

But it is showing me list in number instead of alphabets like below:

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Juice
   Am I doing something wrong here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Also asked here
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3978246

Short answer would be try this

```
<ol style="list-style-type: list-alpha;">
```